# How to exec script to set iterm2 Badge from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, exec, iterm2

I get this bash script from Iterm2 official site.

`printf "\e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=%s\a" $(echo "text" | base64)`

I tried exec like bellow, there is no error, but failed to set iterm2 Badge

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('printf "\e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=%s\a" $(echo "text" | base64)');
```

Comment: It is really clear what you are trying to accomplish but if you wan't to know more about what is going on add a callback

    exec('printf "\e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=%s\a" $(echo "text" | base64)', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // Then console.log those
    });

Comment: @aray12 Log of those things is just `null`, `'e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=ODA4MQo=a'`, `''`. 
I find that when putting the script in a external file e.g. 'setBadgeFormet.sh', and modify the node script to `exec('./setBadgeFormet.sh')` it works!

Comment: Well glad you found a solution. I honestly am not sure why that would change things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setBadgeFormat.js =>

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var rawBadgeFormat = 'test'
var base64BadgeFormat = new Buffer(rawBadgeFormat).toString('base64')
var setBadgeFormatCmd = 'printf "\\e]1337;SetBadgeFormat=' + base64BadgeFormat + '\\a"'
require('child_process').exec(setBadgeFormatCmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    process.stdout.write(stdout); // this line actually do the trick
    process.stderr.write(stderr);
});
```