# How to set iterm2 Badge from vim?

Tags: vim, iterm2

I want to call the function `iterm2_set_user_var VARIABE VALUE` from vim/neovim using `call system()`. However, I get the following.

`zsh:1: command not found: iterm2_set_user_var
shell returned 127`

This is already done in node.js: [How to exec script to set iterm2 Badge from nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613285/how-to-exec-script-to-set-iterm2-badge-from-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've defined `iterm2_set_user_var` as a shell function in your zsh config somewhere.  Vim doesn't invoke a login shell with the `system` function.  I think you have two options:

1. Change `shellcmdflag` to force a login shell by adding `l` to the flags currently there.  This would affect all `:!` commands in vim as well.
2. Define `iterm2_set_user_var` as an executable somewhere in your `$PATH`.

Either should work fine.

Comment: For the second solution. I tried ```:call system("source iterm_integration.zsh && iterm2_set_user_var VARIABE VALUE ```. It dit not give any errors. However, the badge did not change :(.

As for the first one. I really don't know how to do it. And I am under the impression that it will be a very costly operation.

Comment: in vim there is a way to write buffer content to stdout usinf ```:w !tee```. However, I could not find a way to write a variable to stdout. This is what really blocking me.

Comment: I see this iterm2 integration stuff is way more complex than I initially thought.  I've gone down a bit of a rabbit hole and I haven't actually gotten it to work yet.  If I get it to work I'll update this answer.

Comment: I ran out of time to get this working 100% but I did have some success by ignoring the iterm2_* functions and sending the escape sequences myself from vim.  I would suggest that as an avenue for you to investigate.

Comment: I tried that too. I was not successful. As I could not find anything that could write some arbitrary data (NOT BUFFER CONTENT) to stdout in vim.